# C# Moq Find and FindAsync

Tags: c#, entity-framework, moq

I know there are a few articles on this topic, but I can't really find any helpful answers. I want to enable the Find and FindAsync methods of the Entity Framework for anonymous types. We are a larger company and the following is not my code, but maybe it will help to find a solution.

```cs
var dataList = new List<T>();
var data = dataList.AsQueryable();

var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<T>>();

mockSet.As<IDbAsyncEnumerable<T>>().Setup(m => m.GetAsyncEnumerator()).Returns(new TestDbAsyncEnumerator<T>(data.GetEnumerator()));
mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(new TestDbAsyncQueryProvider<T>(data.Provider));
mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator());

mockSet.Setup(d => d.Add(It.IsAny<T>())).Callback<T>((s) => dataList.Add(s));
mockSet.Setup(d => d.Remove(It.IsAny<T>())).Callback<T>((s) => dataList.Remove(s));
mockSet.Setup(d => d.RemoveRange(It.IsAny<IEnumerable<T>>())).Callback<IEnumerable<T>>(range => range.ToList().ForEach(item => dataList.Remove(item)));
mockSet.Setup(d => d.Include(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(mockSet.Object);
mockSet.Setup(d => d.AsNoTracking()).Returns(mockSet.Object);
mockSet.Setup(d => d.FindAsync(It.IsAny<object[]>())).Returns( **** );
```

I want to use the Entity Framework methods Find and FindAsync with moq for unit-testing.

Comment: What is stopping you, exactly?

Comment: In the last line I have problems. I don't know how to access the index of the anonymous type. The input parameter of the FindAsync method is an array of objects, with these keyValues I have to reference the objects of the dataList, I think. Maybe I have problems with the syntax too.

Comment: A real DB would have to. But this only needs to respond with a(ny) result to _any_ input. If you want _specific_ return for _specific_ input, you cannot setup for `It.IsAny`

Comment: There are plenty of nuget packages which can help you to reduce the mocking burden: https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=EntityFramework+moq. I would suggest to pick one and give it a try.